# AkkaHTTP : How to access captured values from the path when using mutlpart upload ( entity(as[ Multipart.FormData]) )

Tags: akka, spray, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to access captured values from path while uploading a file but unable to get the idea on implementation.

Here is the sample code:

```
trait TestRoute extends {
  val regEx = """(\w+)""".r
  def testRoute: Route = path("testing" / regEx / regEx / regEx){
    post {
      //How do i Access (captured regex from the path) inside entity
      entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { fileData => {
        complete {
           "UpLoadDOne"
        }  
       }
    }
   }
}
```

http://localhost:9000/testing/A/B/C

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use spray, you will need something like:

```
import spray.routing.PathMatchers.Segment

trait TestRoute extends {

  def testRoute: Route = path("testing" / Segment / Segment / Segment){ case (A, B, C) =>
    post {
      entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { fileData =>
        complete {
          "UpLoadDOne"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```